# Pandas all possible combinations of two columns

Tags: python, pandas, combinations

I have such a table:

```
    A    B   C 
1   1    2   3 
2   5    6   7
```

I want to extract all combination with two columns as separate data frame:

```
    A    B   
1   1    2   
2   5    6

    A    C 
1   1    3 
2   5    7 

    B   C 
1   2   3 
2   6   7
```

How to accomplish that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) in loop with [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
from  itertools import combinations

for c in combinations(df.columns, 2):
    print (df.loc[:, c])
   A  B
1  1  2
2  5  6
   A  C
1  1  3
2  5  7
   B  C
1  2  3
2  6  7
```

If need list of DataFrames:

```
L = [df.loc[:, c] for c in combinations(df.columns, 2)]
print (L)
[   A  B
1  1  2
2  5  6,    A  C
1  1  3
2  5  7,    B  C
1  2  3
2  6  7]
```

Or dict of DataFrames:

```
d = {f'{"_".join(c)}': df.loc[:, c]for c in combinations(df.columns, 2)}
print (d)
{'A_B':    A  B
1  1  2
2  5  6, 'A_C':    A  C
1  1  3
2  5  7, 'B_C':    B  C
1  2  3
2  6  7}
```